# Replace string pattern in C#

Tags: c#

I have a few sentences inside that are some words that I want to decode.

The pattern of words to be deleted is "&.....;"

.... = Everything

```
<title>دب&#1740;رخانه خبرنامه انجمن علوم باغبان&#1740; ا&#1740;ران به گروه تول&#1740;دات گ&#1740;اه&#1740; پرد&#1740;س ابور&#1740;حان دانشگاه تهران انتقال &#1740;افت . </title>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, what are you asking about?

Comment: What Div are you talking about?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's html encoded string, Just decode it using [HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8) utility method.

```
        // Decode the encoded string.
        HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(code, myWriter);
        string myDecodedString = myWriter.ToString();
```